# How to send messages in mobile as well as email on contact form submission for the client

Tags: wordpress, email, mobile, message, contact-form-7

My client has a website but doesn't check emails often. He has a lot of web enquiries through the online contact form. He carries a mobile phone though.Now he wants to have a message in his mobile as well as email from the contact form submission.How to send contact form details that's submitted through the website to his mobile phone as SMS along with email?The site is in wordpress and using contact form 7

Answer (score 1):

You could send an SMS message, but that would get crazy really quick. Why not have your client set up an email app on their mobile device? All email will be accessible from their phone.